# How to calculate the total value based on object key value pair and show it in card - PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

Trying to create reports using PowerBI, where I can easily upload JSON file and populate the data without any problem. Since Im new to powerBI, I'm not able get proper information for my issue.

Below is my sample JSON data. I want to show the different status counts in card view, (i.e) need to show total number of customer, Active, InActive, Suspended etc

```
 {
        "cutomerConList": [
            {
                "custID": "asd",
                "conStatus": "Active"
            },
            {
                "custID": "asd",
                "conStatus": "Active"
            },
            {
                "custID": "iyu",
                "conStatus": "InActive"
            },
            {
                "custID": "fsd",
                "conStatus": "Suspended"
            },
            {
                "custID": "asd",
                "conStatus": "Hold"
            },
            {
                "custID": "awe",
                "conStatus": "Hold"
            },
            {
                "custID": "bnn",
                "conStatus": "Hold"
            },
            {
                "custID": "err",
                "conStatus": "Suspended"
            },
            {
                "custID": "zxcvx",
                "conStatus": "Active"
            },
            {
                "custID": "iuo",
                "conStatus": "Suspended"
            },
            {
                "custID": "gfytr",
                "conStatus": "Active"
            },
            {
                "custID": "jfghj",
                "conStatus": "Active"
            },
        ]
    }
```

Since the documentation is vague, not able to find the solution. Could someone tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here:

```
countOf = COUNTROWS(VALUES(j[cutomerConList.custID]))
Hold = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(VALUES(j[cutomerConList.custID])), all(j), j[cutomerConList.conStatus] = "Hold")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @msta42a .. and i also found inbuild "NEW QUICK MEASEURE" option powerBI desktop . I accept answer too